# Using NON-TFRecord protocol buffers with Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tfrecord

I have data that is encoded as a google protocol buffer, but not as a `TFRecords tf.example()`. So I would need to use the normal python protocol buffer functions like `ParseFromString()` to deserialize the messages before passing them to `Tensorflow` to train my model.

I was just wondering if there was a good way to deserialize this type of data, since I can't use the standard `Tensorflow` dataset function to parse this data. I might be able to put these functions into a `tf.py_function()` but I was not sure if that was a good way to do it since according to Aurelien Geron's book on Tensorflow version 2(chapter 13), this makes the code slower and less portable.

Any suggestions on how to create a data ingestion pipeline for non-TFRecords protocol buffer datasets?

Comment: Any solution found?